# Programmatically modify VO Display Hint in UI Hints to hide attribute

Tags: oracle-adf

How to set the UI hint : display hint to hide for an attribute in  a VO programmatically at runtime based on some condition.

It is possible when the VO is bound to a page by modifying the 'rendered' attribute.But how would I modify the VO attribute's control hint i.e display hints as 'Hide' at the model layer itself, programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
((AttributeDefImpl) vo.findAttributeDef(fieldName)).setProperty(
                                AttributeHints.ATTRIBUTE_DISPLAY_HINT,
                                AttributeHints.ATTRIBUTE_DISPLAY_HINT_HIDE);
```